# JavaScript: Trying to write two generic methods to read(get) and write(set) properties() in (.properties) file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have tried different npm modules like node-properties-parser, npm-properties.
But nothing worked out successfully.

Can some one help me out in doing so..

Thanks in Advance,
Anil

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and provide [mcve] of your code and explain what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: “I have tried” – How did that look like? What has worked and what did not work?